# Perl - Summarize Data in File

Tags: perl, file, sum

Whats the best way to summarize data from a file that has around 2 million records in Perl?

For eg: A file like this,

ABC|XYZ|DEF|EGH|100

ABC|XYZ|DEF|FGH|200

SDF|GHT|WWW|RTY|1000

SDF|GHT|WWW|TYU|2000

Needs to be summarized on the first 3 columns like this,

ABC|XYZ|DEF|300

SDF|GHT|WWW|3000

Chris

Comment: You want to sum the number in the final column for all records where the first three columns match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there are always five columns, the fifth of which is numeric, and you always want the first three columns to be the key...

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %totals_hash;

while (<>)
{
  chomp;
  my @cols = split /\|/;

  my $key = join '|', @cols[0..2];

  $totals_hash{$key} += $cols[4];
}

foreach (sort keys %totals_hash)
{
  print $_, '|', $totals_hash{$_}, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hash as:

```
my %hash;
while (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        my @tmp = split/\|/;     # split each line on |
        my $value = pop @tmp;    # last ele is the value
        pop @tmp;                # pop unwanted entry
        my $key = join '|',@tmp; # join the remaining ele to form key

        $hash{$key} += $value;   # add value for this key
}

# print hash key-values.
for(sort keys %hash) {
        print $_ . '|'.$hash{$_}."\n";
}
```

[**Ideone link**](http://www.ideone.com/W2DTP)

Comment: Now for a little tougher one,

Comment: What if there were more than one column to summarize?

Comment: If there's more than one column this starts to sound like a job for SQL, which is designed for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your input file has its records in separate lines.

```
perl -n -e 'chomp;@a=split/\|/;$h{join"|",splice@a,0,3}+=pop@a;END{print map{"$_: $h{$_}\n"}keys%h}' < inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

1-2-3-4 I declare *A CODE-GOLF WAR!!!* (Okay, a *reasonably readable* code-golf dust-up.)

```
my %sums;
m/([^|]+\|[^|]+\|[^|]+).*?\|(\d+)/ and $sums{ $1 } += $2 while <>;
print join( "\n", ( map { "$_|$sums{$_}" } sort keys %sums ), '' );
```

Answer (score -1):

Sort to put all records with the same first 3 triplets next to each other. Iterate through and kick out a subtotal when a different set of triplets appears.

```
$prevKey="";
$subtotal=0;
open(INPUTFILE, "<$inFile");
@lines=<INPUTFILE>;
close (INPUTFILE);
open(OUTFILE, ">$outFile");
@sorted=sort(@lines);
foreach $line(@lines){
    @parts=split(/\|/g, $line);
    $value=pop(@parts);
    $value-=0; #coerce string to a number
    $key=$parts[0]."|".$parts[1]."|".$parts[2];
    if($key ne $prevKey){
        print OUTFILE "$prevKey|$subtotal\n";
        $prevKey=$key;
        $subtotal=0;
        }
    $subtotal+=$value;
    }
close(OUTFILE);
```

If sorting 2 million chokes your box then you may have to put each record into a file based on the group and then do the subtotal for each file.

Comment: -1. Why should the OP be forced to read the whole file at once when it can all be done in one pass without having the whole thing in memory?

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for being charitable about it. I'm not trying to ding you, just the answer. I'm sure you're a good person and a good programmer on the whole. :-)

Comment: My bad, I retract the comment. I'm going to learn how to process files properly. Thanks for the correction. :)